# how to make FeignClient handle custom id field in parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign, openfeign

This is my feign method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/spaces/{spaceId}")
void deleteSpace(SpaceId spaceId);
```

and SpaceId field is

```
public class SpaceId implements Serializable {
  @JsonValue
  String id;
}
```

What I want is that when I call `deleteSpace(new SpaceId("1"))`, it calls DELETE to endpoint `DELETE /spaces/1`. Is it doable with FeignClient?

Comment: I just found out it just work as I expected. I was not working before because of another problem.